# HTML5 video with controls but customize it: disable play/pause button and seekbar

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Very simple question almost described in the title.

I want to have controls on HTML5 video (mainly for loader, audio, and fullscreen), but I want to disable pausing and changing position.

How can I hide the play/pause button and seekbar completely? JS solution is also applicable from my side, but it needs to be browser-independent.

Note: I'm not using any libraries. It's a plain html video tag:

```
<video controls>
</video>
```

Comment: Lose the `controls` attribute and add your own controls with HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The default controls are browser specific and cannot be modified.